# How can unwrap html by attribute

Tags: javascript, html

How can I unwrap html by attribute:

```
<div dir="rtl"><div><div dir="rtl"><h2>test</h2></div></div></div>
```

Should to change to:

```
<div><h2>test</h2></div>
```

Note: this doesn't help

```
   unwrap(document.querySelector('[dir="rtl"]'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

unwrap is a jQuery statement

```js
$("[dir=rtl]").each(function() { $(this).children().unwrap() })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div dir="rtl">
  <div>
    <div dir="rtl">
      <h2>test</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Vanilla JS (from https://plainjs.com/javascript/manipulation/unwrap-a-dom-element-35/)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[dir=rtl]').forEach(el => {
  const parent = el.parentNode;
  while (el.firstChild) parent.insertBefore(el.firstChild, el);
  parent.removeChild(el)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div dir="rtl">
  <div>
    <div dir="rtl">
      <h2>test</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Define this `unwrap()` function:

```
function unwrap(el, selector) {
  var descendantsArr = Array.from(el.querySelectorAll(selector));

  if (el.matches(selector))
    removeSelf(el);

  descendantsArr.forEach(d => unwrap(d, selector));

  function removeSelf(el) {
    var childNodesArr = Array.from(el.childNodes),
        parent = el.parentElement;

    el.remove();

    childNodesArr.forEach(n => {
        parent.appendChild(n);
    })
  }
}
```

Then use it:

```
unwrap(yourRootElement, '[dir="rtl"]');
```

`yourRootElement` might be `document.body` (if you want to scan the entire body) or some root element where you want the scanning to start from.

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vszux3f/)